# Issue in opening two dropdown at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here id dropdown fiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/ym8t7Lhj/

The issue i am facing is i am having two dropdowns, if i click on one dropdown another dropdown is also opening.
Can any one help me out in this.

**Script**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("myclass"); 
         $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
         });

        $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {

            var text = $(this).html();
            $('.dropdown dt a').toggleClass('myclass');
            $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
        });      
    });
```

Comment: **Suggestion** you are repeating id `sample` which is a invalid html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("myclass"); 
         $(this).closest('dl').find('ul').toggle();
 });

 $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {

            var text = $(this).html();
             $(this).closest('dl').find('dt a').toggleClass('myclass').find('span').html(text);

            $(this).closest('ul').hide();
            $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("myclass");
        $(this).closest(".dropdown").find("dd ul").toggle();
    });

    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        var parent = $(this).closest(".dropdown");
        parent.find("dd ul").toggle();
        parent.find('dt a').toggleClass('myclass');
        parent.find("dt a span").html(text);
        parent.find('dt ul').hide();
        $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
    });
});
```

Note: Toggle the elements with respect to the clicked element.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/ym8t7Lhj/6/)

Comment: @AshadShanto where did I use same id?

Comment: thanks and in ur code if i click inside the any of the "li" the dropdown must close but it is not actually closing.

Comment: yes i upvoted it, if u give it in seperately i can give tick mark also.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();` with the following:

```
$(this).parent().next().find("ul").toggle();
```

Full code:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
             $(this).toggleClass("myclass");    
             $(this).parent().next().find("ul").toggle();
          });

            $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {

                var text = $(this).html();
                var thisRoot = $(this).closest('.dropdown');
                thisRoot.find('dt a').toggleClass('myclass');
                thisRoot.find("dt a span").html(text);
                thisRoot.find("dd ul").hide();
                $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
            });      
        });
```

Comment: Xminds in ur code if i select any li like india in the second dropdown also it is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same selector for both drop down. Try adding ID on them then use $('dropdown1') and $('dropdown2')

```
[Working Code][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/ym8t7Lhj/5/
```

Comment: Goe actually you are using like different id's if i want 10 dropdown i should repeat the code, code optimization also necessary. any how thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use ID for each. Only you have to remember to access onclick
>   element via  **$(this)**
>
> So it will Only give you the element only..Not other with this same
>   Class.